# Why does Panel from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel returns null in unit testing using C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2019

I have a designer class with name `ExpenseReceipts.aspx.designer.cs` in which a partial class ExpenseReciepts contains

```
public partial class ExpenseReceipts {
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel ResultPanel;
}
```

I have another class ExpenseReceipts.aspx.cs within the module which makes use of this `ResultPanel`.

```
public partial class ExpenseReceipts : LayoutsPageBase
{
public void HandleRecordsNotFound()
        {
            ResultPanel.Visible = false;
            NoItemsMessage.Text = "No Items Found!!!";
            NoItemsMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            NoItemsPanel.Visible = true;
        }
}
```

This works fine as far as the production code goes but the problem arises when I try to write the unit test for the same.
I have the following method trying to shim everything here.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void HandleRecordsNotFound_ShouldMakeNoResultPanelVisible()
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                bool flag = false;

                ShimControl.AllInstances.VisibleSetBoolean = (PANEL, BOOLEAN) => { };
                ShimLabel.AllInstances.TextSetString = (LABEL, TEXT) => { };
                ShimWebControl.AllInstances.ForeColorSetColor = (WEBCONTROL, FORECOLOR) => { };
                ShimControl.AllInstances.VisibleSetBoolean = (CONTROL, BOOLEAN) => { flag = true; };
                ExpenseReceipts expenseReceipts = new ExpenseReceipts();
                expenseReceipts.HandleRecordsNotFound();
                Assert.IsTrue(flag);
            }
        }
```

It FAILS because of the exception thrown in HandleRecordsNotFound saying `NUll pointer exception` indicating -  `ResultPanel` is null.

Kindly help me fix this.
Thanks in advance.
PS: I am using Sharepoint 2019.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shimming method I was following was wrong. It is not the right way to write tests for the UI controls.

Here's what I did:

```
public void HidePanelControl_ShouldSetVisibleToFalse() {
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    JEUploadWorkflowLinkWPUserControl 
    userControl = new JEUploadWorkflowLinkWPUserControl();
    userControl.HidePanelControl(panel);
    Assert.IsFalse(panel.Visible);
}
```